# Is it harmful to write on yourself with pen ink?

Tags: dermatology, toxicity, poison, artificial

If so, what are the chemicals present that make it toxic?

I imagine it depends on the pen.  Specifically, I'm asking about bic pens and sharpies, but I'm curious in general.